# What are the transfer functions of \$G(s)+G(s)^*\$ and \$G(s)-G(s)^*\$?

Tags: transfer-function, state-space

Consider the following system:

\begin{align}
&\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t),\\
&y(t)=Cx(t),
\end{align}

where \$x\in\mathbb{C}^n\$ is the state and \$y\in\mathbb{C}^m\$ is the output, \$A,B,C\$ are complex constant matrices with appropriate dimensions.

Then the loop transfer function is \$G(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B\$. I want to find the transfer function of these 3 systems:

1. \$G(s)^*G(s)\$,
2. \$G(s)+G(s)^*\$,
3. \$G(s)-G(s)^*\$.

---

First we find that \$G(s)^*=G(-s)^T=-B^T(sI+A^T)^{-1}C^T\$. Here, \$A^*\$ is a conjugate transpose of \$A\$, and \$A^T\$ is a transpose of \$A\$.

1. I have searched this thing online, and found that we can rewrite it as \$G(s)^*G(s)=\hat{C}(sI-\hat{A})^{-1}\hat{B}\$, where $$\hat{A}=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\C^TC&-A^T\end{bmatrix},\hat{B}=\begin{bmatrix}B\\0\end{bmatrix}\,\hat{C}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-B^T\end{bmatrix}$$
2. So can I similarly rewrite \$G(s)+G(s)^*=\tilde{C}(sI-\tilde{A})^{-1}\tilde{B}\$, where $$\tilde{A}=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&-A^T\end{bmatrix},\tilde{B}=\begin{bmatrix}B\\C^T\end{bmatrix}\,\tilde{C}=\begin{bmatrix}C&-B^T\end{bmatrix}$$
3. and \$G(s)-G(s)^*=\bar{C}(sI-\bar{A})^{-1}\bar{B}\$ where $$\bar{A}=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&-A^T\end{bmatrix},\bar{B}=\begin{bmatrix}B\\C^T\end{bmatrix}\,\bar{C}=\begin{bmatrix}C&B^T\end{bmatrix}?$$

I want to find the transfer function of 2) and 3) using \$A,B\$ and \$C\$.

Comment: Hi Lee, You have mentioned the answer to the three system transfer functions in terms of new A, B, and C matrices. You have also mentioned the formula to get the new A, B, and C matrices. So won't substitution of the matrices in the equation solve it? Can you please explain what is the issue in this?

Comment: @SrinivasanMP the issue is that I am not sure if 2. and 3. are correct. Is it true that \$G(s)+G(s)^*=\tilde{C}(sI-\tilde{A})^{-1}\tilde{B}\$ and \$G(s)-G(s)^*=\bar{C}(sI-\bar{A})^{-1}\bar{B}\$ as above?